# Stack Exchange doesn't know when I last checked my global inbox?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, email-notification, subscription

I am subscribed to get my unread inbox items every 3 hours. It's working well, but today I noticed something quite weird:

> [image]

For sake of future search, adding the text:

> The following item was added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2015-05-18

But that's just not true, I checked my inbox yesterday. Not 7 months ago.

Can it be fixed, or did I miss something?

Even going to my [Network  Profile global inbox tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) did not "fix" this, got today another email with the same date as yesterday.

Comment: Shh... I think we might be on the trace of the elusive _other_ kind of leap year...

Comment: @Stijn maybe the time when this feature went live... dunno. But it really amazes me why they don't fix it, or at least remove that date until they fix it.

Comment: I have the exact same date shown in my emails

Comment: @MattHealy yup, that's the bug. Amazingly,  they **still** didn't bother to fix it or even take a look even though it reach thousands of people every day and makes SE look... well, not professional.

Comment: I would have preferred removing the date.  This fix broke other things. :-(  (Fortunately there's a [workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299802/162102), but still...)

Comment: @Monica huh, had no idea it would cause such side effect, i.e. that such "deep logic" was broken behind the scenes. I just saw a broken date. To be honest, I'll support feature request asking to remove the date in favor of getting back the old behavior, it's really not that important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic for updating that date was broken by inbox changes in May 2015, which is why many users see "last checked" dates around then. It had been fixed, and will now update appropriately whenever you open [the inbox in the top bar](/topbar/inbox) or [view it on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).

Comment: Awesome! Consider yourself as the winner of Legendary Bug Fixer badge. :-D

Comment: _the inbox in the top bar_ leads to an ugly page

Comment: @SagarV Yeah, it's usually loaded into the dropdown, where it's styled appropriate, but I can't link directly to that. :)

Comment: Ah man, I think this might've wiped out my inbox notifications. I think I had like 3000 - 4000 of them pending.

Comment: @Mysticial on one hand, I understand that you have to skip some of the notifications. But on the other hand, I don't understand why you want to skip one. Isn't you curious on responses talking to you?

Comment: @Ooker I never skipped any notifications. I've always gone to the SE inbox to get them. But until today, doing that didn't clear the notifications. So I had some 3-4k of notifications in the top bar because it's been like 2 years since I've clicked on it from there. But I always check my SE inbox.

Comment: @Mysticial on man, that's weird. But one bright side is that the counting number disappears every click.

Comment: @Jeremy I might be pushing my luck here, but there is [another old bug which is really annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284783/the-new-post-modification-notification-constantly-messes-up-editing) and might also be something trivial that went wrong... any chance to take a look? Thanks in advantage!