# The new post modification notification constantly messes up editing

Tags: bug, edits, live-refresh

The change that [introduced this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283925/posts-disappear-briefly-then-reload-when-i-click-them) continues to cause trouble beyond that specific bug (which has been fixed). Please go back to the old notification mechanism, which largely stayed out the way.

With the new system, if someone modifies a post, just about anything you do anywhere near that post will reload. This is particularly annoying when you're editing a post and someone else edits it — the notification comes up, and when you do innocent, normal things (say, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C to save your changes so you can then refresh to see what changed and make sure not to overwrite them) trigger the reload, making you lose your edits (and making the page jump to a completely different scroll position, for reasons that are unclear). I've wasted a lot of time the last few weeks as a result of this.

Please either ditch it or fix it.

Comment: I'd say ditch it.

Comment: I'd say fix it.

Answer (score 7):

This is really starting to annoy me. Not only forces it to reload when you are editing, throwing away everything you have, it also breaks normal functionality, like voting to close, flagging, etc.

If you click the *close* link under a post when an edit has been made for example, the post quickly flashes and shows the edited post. Clicking *close* again then says I can only do that every 3 seconds. The same when I vote on a post, it is just annoying.

Please ditch this auto-update stuff and let us decide when to view the updated post.

Comment: Agreed, this is the kind of things that might cause active users to be less active, and drive them away. Using a buggy system doesn't feel good.